# Is there a reason to lose 1,000 chess games

Tags: online-chess, computer-chess

I lost over a 1000 games on chess.com
Is it because I make the same mistakes?

Here is [one recent game](https://www.chess.com/game/live/69446892571?username=tetrahedronx7) I played as White with 30 min for each side.

```
[Title "tetrahedronx7 (OP)- TheCessCan"]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 h5 2. d4 Rh6 3. Nf3 Rd6 4. Nc3 Re6 5. d5 Rh6 6. Bd3 c6 7. O-O cxd5 8. exd5 e6 9. dxe6 dxe6 10. Qe1 g6 11. Be2 b6 12. Bxh6 Ba6 13. Bxa6 Nxh6 14. Rd1 Nxa6 15. Rxd8+ Kxd8 16. Qd1+ Ke8 17. Qe2 Ng4 18. Qxa6 Kd8 19. Rd1+ Kc7 20. Nb5+ Kc6 21. Qa3 Bxa3 22. bxa3 Kxb5 23. Rb1+ Kc6 24. Nd4+ Kd5 25. Rb5+ Kxd4 26. Rb4+ Kc5 27. Rb3 Nxh2 28. Kxh2 Rd8 29. Rc3+ Kd4 30. Rb3 Rd5 31. Rd3+ Kc4 32. Rxd5 exd5 33. Kh1 h4 34. Kh2 Kc3 35. Kh3 g5 36. Kg4 Kxc2 37. Kxg5 Kd2 38. Kxh4 d4 39. f4 d3 40. Kh3 Kc1 41. Kg3 d2 42. Kf2 d1=Q 0-1
```

Comment: Related posts by the same user:  1. [I lost over 1000 games in chess.com rapid?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/41530/26335) and 2. [I have a 400 elo rating and have lost over 900 games in chess.com. Should I give up](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/41513/26335)

Comment: Be [careful with your queen](https://www.chess.com/game/live/69552980487?username=tetrahedronx7)

Answer (score 2):

If this is a typical game, you're losing games because you're missing one-move tactics, not because you're using your queen too much. You don't even move your queen until move 10.

Here are some of your obvious errors:

Move 3 - you can win the exchange with Bxh6. And again on moves 6-11.

Move 13 - if you capture the f8 bishop, you're up a whole rook.

Move 14 - rather than threatening his queen, retreat your bishop from a6, and you're up a whole rook.

Move 21 - you dropped your queen. Nfd4+ looks better.

Move 22 - you should have recaptured the bishop with your knight, then your opponent couldn't capture it.

Move 25 - you hang your knight.

Move 30 - you miss a simple x-ray that would win the rook, Rd3+.

Comment: Is that of sign that I have below average iq?

Comment: @Tetrahedronx800 there is no correlation between IQ and chess ability.

Comment: Thanks for the answer make sure to analyze
Than to be impulsive.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have identified a possible problem: "use my queen a lot". You need to verify if that indeed is your problem.  One way would be to analyze your games more carefully. I think it is best to do that over the board, face-to-face with a more experienced player, but many people believe doing it by computer works fine lso.  (This is one of the main reasons for saving your scores, at least as a beginner. )

Once you have verified that your queen moves are indeed your weak spot, ... you will probably avoid making them without closer analysis.  Play your next 1000 games, and see if you are right.

Good luck!

(Observation: Question has been entirely reedited since I posted this.  I let the answer stand though ...)

Comment: I am upset that I lose 1000 games.

Comment: And I have to keep resigning.

Comment: I have to keep on resigning because I lost my queen

Comment: @ Tetrahedronx800 Paul Keres, the Estonian GM, wrote (if I remember correctly) in one of his books that he thought that his mastery of chess was due to the thousands of games he played with classmates in school between lessons and on lunch breaks. As in everything, mastery comes at a prize -- and part of that prize is eating pain in the form of lost games. Not everyone asks what to do about it ... but you did.

Comment: Well I keep losing a lot is that bad thing? Because grandmaster don't lose a 1000 games like me.

Comment: Keres was not a GM when he played all those matches at school.  I don't remember that he said that he lost all of his games, but he probably lost a fair bit.  But he was playing against someone who could say "You shouldn't have moved that Bishop", or "That's what happen when you don't castle", or things like that.  Getting that kind of feedback ... and fairly quickly after the game ... helps learning.

Comment: I think losing 1100 games is bad for me because I was playing too fast?

Answer (score 1):

You say that it was a 30 minute game. However, a few things that you might want to ask yourself:

- How much time did you actually utilise?
- Are you probably moving a little too quickly?
- Are you checking the placement of all your pieces, and all of your opponents pieces before every move? Often times, at this rating level, players are susceptible to ignoring queen - bishop battery (mate in 1), or co-ordinated knight - queen mate.
- Are you focusing on just making the next move, or are you also spending time evaluating what your opponent plans to do next, and what they could do after you respond?
- After examining the above points, and before you make your move, do you conduct a "Blunder check"? For instance, move 21. Qa3 gave away a free queen.
- When the game is lost, do you just move onto the "Next" game in frustration, or are you also spending time reviewing your mistakes?

This is by no means an exhaustive list, but inculcating these habits into your game could help you stabilise your rating and eventually improve upon it. Solving puzzles, learning tactics, etc. is all useful, but I'd opine that nothing else scores better than being disciplined with how you play and review your own games.

Comment: I see your point.

Comment: Thanks. If I may add one more thing... it also seems that you're worried about the number of games lost. How about thinking in terms of the **percentage** of games won, lost or drawn? I reckon that is a more objective evaluation, as opposed to a self-imposed threshold of the number of losses.

Comment: I lose thousands games is that bad?

Comment: It's all a part of learning. If you're going to play 10k games, it's quite all right to lose 5k of them. As mentioned before, I think it's best to not count the number of losses and focus on improving, if that's what your goal is.