# I lose more than I won? And I can't stand it

Tags: computer-chess, losing

I lose like almost 1700 games in rapid and it's bad and I feel like I'm going have a hemmorage because it's pissing me off and bad I am? is it because my intellectual disability or what?

Comment: Related from OP:  [I have a 400 elo rating and have lost over 900 games in chess.com. Should I give up](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/41513/26335); [I lost over 1000 games in chess.com rapid?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/41530/26335)

Comment: Be careful to avoid giving away pieces for free (e.g., [16...Qd5](https://www.chess.com/game/live/71550859489?username=tetrahedronx7)). Perhaps adding a "blunder check" before you move could help.

Answer (score 2):

Your last post was from February 6th with 1000 games lost. This is not even a month. Lets assume, you lose around 50 % of the games, this means, in this 24 days you played 1400 games, which averages to around 58 games a day.

Lets say, you sleep 8 hours which leaves you with 16 hours non stop play time. Even then each game could have at maximum 16 minutes of play time per game, so the game format that you are playing is for sure less than a 10 minutes game.

But 16 hours of playing a day is rather unlikely, even 8 is hard to stay focused (and motivated if, as you say, you lose a lot).

So that leaves me with the conclusion, that, even though you claim you play rapid, you probably play at bullet or blitz speed and that is just a very bad choice for a beginner. You don't have the game intuition for that yet. At that speeds you can't calculate anymore and have to 'feel' which moves will be good and this you only get by calculating first a lot.

So my recommendation, the same as you will read it anywhere when some beginner asks how to get better, is, to slow down and play fewer games. At least 10 minutes thinking per side, better yet 15 or more. Only like this you will really have a time to calculate and get an understanding of the game. Also go over your games afterwards and see where you made your mistakes and try not to repeat that anymore. But don't lazily let the engine show you where you made mistakes, but try to find it yourself first.

Also, do a lot of puzzles. Like this you will see many different positions and think them through. But you have to try to achieve a success ratio of at least 60 % I would say. If you just look at it for a second, make random moves until you accidentally find the correct one you will not get anything out of them.

Comment: But is losing 1700 games is bad?

Comment: But is losing 1700 games is bad?

Comment: @Tetrahedronx800 Not really. Magnus Carlsen has lost ten-thousands or even hundred-thousands of games in his life. But he also won even more. The Elo-System pairs you up with opponents of comparable strength, so you should end up with something around 50 % winning ratio. If you have some improvement in playing strength you will probably have a higher winning rate for a while until it stabilizes again at around 50 %. 
Just if you don't learn a thing from those 1700 played games, then it's bad. If you just play them down without any learning, then it's a waste of time if you don't enjoy it.

Comment: "Magnus Carlsen has lost ten-thousands or even hundred-thousands of games in his life. But he also won even more" - do you have a reference for this claim ?

Comment: @Peter I have to admit, that "hundred-thousands" might have been exagerated. But looking at his profiles on chess.com (434 losses) and lichess (DrDrunkenstein 246 losses, manwithavan 55 losses, DannyTheDonkey 23 losses, DrNykterstein 2362 losses) I'm already at a couple thousand losses. I somehow don't think though, that this are his main accounts but I couldn't find another one. But I think there are many more from the pre-internet times that are simply not recorded.

Comment: For a more compact example of a Grandmaster having more than 10.000 losses that I now could find is also Daniel Naroditsky. On his chess.com profile he has 7997 losses in bullet, 7212 in blitz and 13 in rapid. And here probably also many 1000 analog losses would have to be added, so ten-thousands doesn't sound so unlikely to me.

Comment: Losing 1700 games means I am rxtxrdxd.

Comment: @Tetrahedronx800 at this point I am not sure whether you are not trolling, sorry. You asked the same question already several times and it seems to me like you never even regarded any of the hints there and instead just reiterated your "I lost x games, I must be stupid" - somebody even pointed out to you, that there is no correlation between IQ and chess skill. If you don't enjoy the game, stop it - nobody forces you to it. If you do enjoy it and you want to improve then take the advice seriously, stop pitying yourself and work on your weaknesses. Maybe get a trainer that tells you which

Comment: Okay is losing 1800 games is horrendous?

Comment: And I still keeping losing.

Comment: @Tetrahedronx800 I recommend opening a new question for that as it now is a completely different situation as to what me and many other people told you earlier... \s

Comment: I am losing more than I
 winning.

Comment: @Tetrahedronx800 good job, keep up the good work.

Comment: Losing 1800 games is bad.

Comment: @Tetrahedronx800 this conversation is really funny. I like talking to you. Always a good feeling if people are listening.